# NeoVim: how to build luarocks (and it's modules) without internet access?

Tags: neovim

I have a Fedora COPR ([personal repo link](https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/dperson/neovim/)). It's in the NeoVim wiki Fedora installation section. There's been interest in getting it into the main Fedora repo.

Koji (the Fedora build tool for all official packages) doesn't allow internet access during a build, though. And I can't figure out how to bundle the LuaRocks modules into the SRPM, or even exactly what I should bundle... any help would be appreciated.

My spec file can be found [here](https://au2pb.org/srpms/neovim-stable.spec), if it helps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you build with `make USE_BUNDLED_DEPS=OFF` (or `cmake -DUSE_BUNDLED=OFF` if you're directly running cmake), then none of the 3rd-party dependencies will be built.  It will use whatever is available on the system.

In that case, you don't need LuaRocks at all.  You just need to have the required lua modules packaged.